# JasperReports: Removing a group band when its empty

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have two sub reports in a group footer band. All I want is when this group footer is empty (in other words sub reports are empty) this group footer should not take space on report. Because its printing a empty page between two reports. I have set the property stack footer at the bottom so when sub reports print it starts on new page. I am using *JasperReports* 4.5

Comment: Have you tried the Flag isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" on the sub report?

Comment: i have solved this problem.using print when expression thanks